# CUDA version mismatch on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, cuda

I'm trying to use the CUDA toolkit on Ubuntu 18.04. 
I installed the CUDA toolkit by using

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6
```

This installed CUDA 9.1, verified by using `nvcc --version`, which showed

```
nvcc: release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

However, `nvidia-smi` shows

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.14       Driver Version: 430.14       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================+
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    209MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

<sup>[manually transcribed – see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXdvc.png) for verification]</sup>

which says CUDA version is 10.2. 
So what version of CUDA do I have installed?

P.S. I am also unable to find `/usr/local/cuda`. 
Is this related in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `nvidia-smi` is only showing the current driver's CUDA compatability version, and not indicative of what CUDA is installed.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html